# How many length-$k$ ternary strings have evenly many of a given symbol?

Tags: combinatorics, recursion, combinatorics-on-words

I write down a string of $k$ letters, where each letter is $X, Y, \text{or } Z.$ The letter $X$ appears an even number of times. How many different sequences of letters could I have written down?

I think I need to start by setting up some cases, and building a recursion from that. I tried but arrived at a really weird form. May I have a start, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_k$ denote the number of sequences of length $k$ with an even number of $X$'s.

For any of the $3^{k-1}$ sequences of length $k-1$, by adding either an $X$ or a $Y$ to the end, you may obtain a sequence with an even number of $X$'s.

Additionally, for each of the $A_{k-1}$ sequences of length $k-1$ with an even number of $X$'s, you may add a $Z$ to the end, to obtain a sequence of length $k$ with an even number of $X$'s.

Thus $A_{k}=3^{k-1}+A_{k-1}$.  As $A_0=1$ we have$$A_k=1+1+3+9+\cdots+3^{k-1}=\frac{3^k+1}2.$$

Comment: This solution allows $0$ $X$s... which is *not* an even number of $X$s.... "$X$ appears an even number of times."  If there are no $X$s, then the OP's condition is *not* obeyed.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - On the contrary: If there are *no* $X$s, then the number of $X$s is $0$, which [is an even number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero) (thus satisfying the OP's condition).

Comment: Note that if we wanted to count only the strings with a ***positive** even number* of $X$s, then we need only subtract $2^k$ from the above accepted answer, there being exactly $2^k$ strings of length $k$ containing no $X$s at all (i.e., composed of only $Y$s and $Z$s).

Comment: @r.e.s:  Well, I suppose.  So you must agree that the letter $K$ *appears* an even number of times... as does the letter $B$.... as does the phrase "Bolivia exports tin."  Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

(The purpose of this post is to show that the two different approaches in the other answers do in fact give the same answer.)

With alphabet $\{X,Y,Z \}$ let $A_k$ be the number of length-$k$ words with evenly many $X$s. As in the answer by @david-g-stork, each such word can be constructed by first choosing where to place the $X$s -- there are $\binom{k}{2r}$ choices, with $r=0..{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}$ (we include $r=0$ to allow words with no $X$s at all) -- then for each choice writing a sequence of only $Y$s and $Z$s in the remaining $k-2r$ places -- there are $2^{k-2r}$ such sequences -- giving 
$$A_k = \sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} {k \choose 2 r} 2^{k-2r}.$$ 
Now, by the Binomial Theorem: $$\begin{align}\binom k0 + \binom k1 x + \binom k2 x^2 + \dots& + \binom{k}{k-1}x^{k-1} + \binom kk x^k = (1 + x)^k\\[2ex]
\binom k0 + \binom k1 (-x) + \binom k2 (-x)^2 + \dots& + \binom{k}{k-1}(-x)^{k-1} + \binom kk (-x)^k = (1 - x)^k\end{align}$$
so, adding these and dividing by $2$ (noting that the odd terms cancel):
$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} {k \choose 2 r} x^{2r}=\frac{(1+x)^k+(1-x)^k}{2}.$$ 
Therefore, $$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} {k \choose 2 r} \left (\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2r}=\frac{\left (\frac{3}{2}\right)^k+\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}{2}$$
and finally
$$A_k = \sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} {k \choose 2 r} 2^{k-2r}=\frac{3^k+1}{2}$$
which is the answer @tkf obtained by a recurrence relation.

---

**NB**: Alternatively, we can consider the two answers as providing a *combinatorial proof* of the identity $$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} {k \choose 2 r} 2^{k-2r}=\frac{3^k+1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Note**:  The other "solutions" here allow $0$ $X$s in a sequence, but the OP writes:  "The letter $X$ appears an even amount of times."  If no $X$ appears, it is incorrect to say "$X$ appears an even amount of times."  For this reason, the other approaches are incorrect, even if they given a simple solution.

Here's the correct solution:

Let $r$ be an indicator for the number of $X$s:  specifically, there are $2 r$ (an even number) of $X$s.  (Of course, $r = 1 \to \lfloor k/2 \rfloor$.)  For a given $r$, the number of ways you can choose those $X$s is:  ${k \choose 2 r}$.  For each such choice, there remain $k - 2 r$ slots to be filled with $Y$s and $Z$s.  For $i$ $Y$s in these slots, there are ${k - 2 r \choose i}$ ways to choose those $Y$s.  (The remaining slots must be $Z$s.)  You must sum for each possible value of $i$, where $i = 0 \to k - 2 r$.

Putting this together, the number of ways for this is given by the sum below in the parentheses.

Now you must sum over all possible values of $r$, i.e., from $r = 1 \to \lfloor k/2 \rfloor$.

$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \left( {k \choose 2 r} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k - 2 r} {k - 2 r \choose i} \right) =$$

$$-2^{-2 \left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor +k-2} \binom{k}{2 \left(\left\lfloor
   \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor +1\right)} \, _3F_2\left(1,-\frac{k}{2}+\left\lfloor
   \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor +1,-\frac{k}{2}+\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor
   +\frac{3}{2};\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor +\frac{3}{2},\left\lfloor
   \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor +2;\frac{1}{4}\right)-2^k+\frac{3^k}{2}+\frac{1}{2})$$

where $F$ is the hypergeometric function.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand, this seems really strange to be a general form for the problem.

Comment: Umm... what does this have to do with "a sequence"?  Are you familiar with the mathematical definition of "sequence"?  Umm... what does this have to do with "probability"?  Are you familiar with the definition of probability?

Comment: Edited the tags.

Comment: Edit the *TITLE*!!!  (And explain why you think this has something to do with Catalan numbers.)

Comment: I think your summations should begin with $r=0$, and the inner sum is then equal to $2^{k-2r}.$ Then, according to Wolfram Alpha, $$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \left( {k \choose 2 r} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k - 2 r} {k - 2 r \choose i} \right) =\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \left( {k \choose 2 r} 2^{k - 2 r} \right)=\frac{3^k+1}2,$$ which is the other (accepted) answer.

Comment: @r.e.s:  I rejected that approach because I didn't consider $0$ to be "an even number of $X$s."

Comment: In that case, your answer simplifies to $\frac{3^k+1}{2}-2^k.$